# How useful are CSS pre-processors (ASS, SCSS, LESS) for Responsive Web Design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, less

I have to work on a RWD project. I was wondering whether I should use LESS to make this task easier. Does using CSS preprocessors offer any advantages while working on RWD? 
*I have a hunch that using media queries in LESS mixins might be time-saving.*

Comment: see http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32

Answer (score 1):

I find them very time-saving, especially [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com) with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). But some people just find it confusing, and there are some new things to learn.

I made some mixins for compass that automatically makes both retina and non-retina sprites and maps them to media queries, this has helped me save a lot of time both in my text editor and in Photoshop. [You can read more about the spriting here.](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)

Here is a example of how I used the mixin function.

```
@mixin pixel-ratio($ratio: 1.5) {
    $dpi: $ratio * 96;
    $opera-ratio: $ratio * 100;
    @media
        only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: #{$ratio}),
        only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: #{$ratio}),
        only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: '#{$opera-ratio}/100'),
        only screen and (   min-device-pixel-ratio: #{$ratio}),
        only screen and (           min-resolution: #{$dpi}dpi),
        only screen and (           min-resolution: #{$ratio}dppx) {
            @content;
    }
}

@include pixel-ratio() {
    //Code here
}
```

I also have this mixin, that makes media queries for both the normal and retina version, I'm not sure that it is the final one, but it should give you an idea about how easy it is to use once you are started.

```
// Usage: @include retina-sprite($name);
@mixin retina-sprite($name, $offset-x: 0, $offset-y: 0, $downscale-adjust: 0, $map: $sprite-sprites, $mapx2: $sprite-retina-sprites) {
    background-image: sprite-url($map);
    background-position: sprite-position($map, $name);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: (image-height(sprite-file($map, $name)) );
    width: image-width(sprite-file($map, $name));
    @include pixel-ratio() {
        // Workaround for https://gist.github.com/2140082
        @if (sprite-position($map, $name) != sprite-position($mapx2, $name)) {
            $posX: round(nth(sprite-position($mapx2, $name, 0, 2 * $offset-x), 1) / 2);
            $posY: round(nth(sprite-position($mapx2, $name, 0, 2 * $offset-y), 2) / 2);
            background-position: $posX $posY;
        }
        // Set image size to the orginal size of the image
        @include background-size(floor(image-width(sprite-path($map)) - $downscale-adjust) auto);
        background-image: sprite-url($mapx2);
    }
}
```

You can try out SCSS with Compass the easy way by installing [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io). This allows you to init a project that comes with all the basic SCSS settings, and then you can try it for yourself.

However it is not that hard to [install](http://compass-style.org/install/) by itself, it just need Ruby.

As one of the comments also point out [thesassway.com](http://thesassway.com/) is a pretty good resource for guides on SCSS/SASS.